# How to use custom dev-tool for Brave Browser?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, brave, brave-browser

I'm debugging wasm code in dev-tool, there is a line limit for displaying the wasm source code, which is 1000*1000 lines by default, when exceeds the limit, it shows ";; .... text is truncated due to the size":
[image]

My wasm is larger than that, so I'm trying to build my custom dev-tools. My environment is Kali Linux + Brave Browser.

According to [this article](https://diverto.hr/en/blog/2020-08-15-WebAssembly-limit/), I commented out the lines:
[image]

And built successfully, the only difference is that the output directory in the article is ".../resources/inspector" and mine is ".../resources/inspector_overlay".

I tried launch it with `--custom-devtools-frontend=file:///root/.../inspector_overlay`, when press F12, the dev-tool fails to open, it shows error:

```
[82506:82549:0121/223355.672780:ERROR:devtools_ui_data_source.cc(306)] Failed to read /root/Downloads/devtools-frontend/out/Default/resources/inspector_overlay/devtools_app.html
[82506:82506:0121/223355.693282:ERROR:CONSOLE(67)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setInspectedTabId')", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_compatibility.js (67)
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I found from [this discuss](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/devtools-dev/c/BENZ8ZTW0Ls/m/7bHpMTdUAwAJ) that the correct path should be `gen/front_end`, so the param is: `--custom-devtools-frontend=file:///root/Downloads/devtools-frontend/out/Default/gen/front_end`